# webview loadUrl(contentprovider example

Tags: android, webview, android-contentprovider

I found webview loadUrl() method works with many types:
finally I have seen this also

content:// URLs pointing to a ContentProvider that is publishing content
available for streaming

from https://www.journaldev.com/9333/android-webview-example-tutorial.

content:// URLs pointing to a ContentProvider that is publishing content
available for streaming

I have searched a lot to find an example about how webview load a webpage using "content:// " urls. I got one link,

http://web.archive.org/web/20101108043507/http://www.techjini.com/blog/2009/01/10/android-tip-1-contentprovider-accessing-local-file-system-from-webview-showing-image-in-webview-using-content/

but that's not complete.

I am a beginner, so i don't know about content provider. Please give me an example of loading a web page using loadUrl("content://package name/htmlfile.html")  in webview.

eg: webview.loadUrl("content://package name/htmlfile.html")

Give me an example, it should be good if it explains about it or github code link.

Comment: what do you want to do? show what have you tried

Comment: `"but that's not complete."` - what do you mean by that?

Comment: actually I am a beginner. I just create a webview project and made a layout with webview and used loadUrl("content:// package name of other apps/html file") but webview doesn't show up

Comment: the example was not complete. or there is no full code. pskink

Comment: so did you create your own, custom `ContentProvider`?

Comment: no, i am a beginner. So i don't know how to use that.

Comment: see [Content provider basics](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics) then

Answer (score 2):

The WebView is an example of Android's View class that allows you to display web pages as a part of your activity layout. All that a WebView does by default is display a web page.

**Adding a WebView to your app**

To add a WebView to your app, you can either include the `<WebView>` element in your activity layout or set the entire Activity window as a WebView in `onCreate()`.

**Load a WebView**

To load a web page in the WebView in the WebView, use `loadurl()`.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(id);
webView.loadUrl("https://www.page.com") // incase you are loading page from 
server.

//Loading page from an asset folder
```

To load a locally available HTML file, place the HTML file in your android/assets folder.Use the following code to load it into the webView

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/termofservice.html);
```

Unless you have a specific user requirement, you should not load HTML pages using the content:// protocol instead use file:// for offline files and `http://` for files available on a remote server.

Before all of this works however, your app needs to have access to the internet permissions, which you can obtain by decalring this on your manifest:

```
<manifest ...>
     <uses-permissions android:name = "android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest... >
```

On SDK 21 and above you will have to request this permission explicitly:
In your MainActivity.java:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[] Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, REQUEST_INTERNET_PERMISSION);
    }
```

You can self-check for the permission before loading the webView incase user denied you the particular permission.

```
int permissionStatus = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(application, Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
    if (permissionStatus == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        return true;
    else if (permissionStatus == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
        return false;
    else
        return false;
```

Comment: I know this bro. I want an example to load webpage using content uri.

Comment: Where is the HTML file you are trying to load, located? Using a content provider to perform this particular task can be agonising, you need to have a good reason why it would not work for you, for instance, if the HTML file is not in your appDir

Comment: actually that was i am saying i want to make a content provider, and put my file in my package name folder in data/data or android folder just like other apps

Comment: With Google new security limitations on file systems, it will be easier and safer to just put it in the assets directory.Would that work for you?

Comment: I edited my question. I know about this and thanks for your help. please check my question again

Comment: The reason to serve data from a content provider is that it's not accessible in your process (e.g. there's another app that provides the content). Sharing files between apps is bad practice and won't be allowed in the future. Content provider is the way to go.